# Why is there no simple "Santa Claus" hat for the winter bash?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2016

When thinking about "special hats" for the Christmas/end-of-year-holidays season ... it would be something like this:

[image]

Wouldn't it make much sense to have something like that in the collection ... and make it available to everybody, right from the beginning?

Comment: How do you know that there is no such hat? I guess that not all secret hats have been discovered yet...

Comment: There is one, and it's called 'Transparency'.

Comment: What I mean is: a hat you have **nothing** to do for. Maybe it becomes available the first time you open that "winter bash" link http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/ ... you know, like a **gift** that comes for **free**. Without **any** specific actions from the user.

Comment: @honk How do I know that there is no hat that comes initially for free ... maybe because it didnt come initially for free?

Comment: @GhostCat: What I mean is: Maybe everybody gets this hat automatically without doing anything in 2 or 3 days...

Comment: Hats have to be **earned**. Granted the criteria might be arbitrary but still....

Comment: There is no Santa hat, because Santa isn't real. The abominable snowman is however. Simple really.

Comment: @GhostCat there are often hats for doing nothing more than visiting the site on a specific day.  There's been at least one this year so far and in past years, there have been a couple more.  That's about a "automatic" as you probably can find now,

Comment: @Paulie_D: Well, you "earn" the 12th hat "011" for collecting 11 hats. That might be interpreted as "you get that hat for free".

Comment: It's not free...you still have to **earn** it by **doing something**.

Comment: We don't value what we don't earn...simples!

Comment: But clicking that link isn't earning? Like earning that one bronze badge for scrolling down the tour page as newbie?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Well, you could earn that hat for successfully becoming a member of Stack Overflow (or any other Stack Exchange site) ;)

Comment: @Paulie_D Err, *who* says that? Is there some ancient tablet of law, cast in stone,  ages ago; or more precisely, punched into *the holy punchcard of SO* 8 years ago, when this community came into existence? A punchcard that reads: "**Anything** that will ever given away on Stackoverflow must be **earned**; there shall never be anything coming free; as that would mean cheerful laughter and unconditional joy which is something the grinches here did not, do not, will not ever support". Or where exactly did that idea originate from?

Comment: @Bart Besides; no xmas presents for you this year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Summarizing the responses given in the comments:

- It looks like other users do not see a need for such a hat coming for free
- To the contrary, receiving things "for free" seems to feel "unnatural" for some users

Answer (score -1):

It is on Winter Bash 2017 but not 2016.